# Unexpected value of Android CallLog.Calls TYPE

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

I have an `Android (2.x)` app that read call logs from `CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI`.

Recently I got an error report that get an unexpected value from `TYPE` field. I assume in the source code that the values should always be `1, 2, 3 (CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE, CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE, and CallLog.Calls.MISSING_TYPE repectively)`

Unfortunately I don't have information about the actual value I got. My problem is, what are the possible values of the `TYPE` field beyond the above three? The Android javadoc explicitly stated "The type of the call (incoming, outgoing or missed)"

Answer (score 15):

There are more types outside of the standard Incoming(1), Outgoing(2) and Missed(3).
So far I have encountered 4 (VoiceMail), 5 (Rejected) and 6 (Refused List).

Comment: what the refused list means in android calllog ?

Comment: @blackjack maybe block contact list

Comment: I would like to know the direction of the different codes. Is voicemail(4) and rejected(5) incoming calls and missed(3) outgoing?

Comment: Are these other codes, particularly 5 and 6, documented anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

```
   final static int Rejected = 5;
   final static int Refused_List = 6;
   final static int Voice_Mail = 4;
```

Comment: I would like to know the direction of the different codes. Is voicemail(4) and rejected(5) incoming calls and missed(3) outgoing?

Comment: On a LYF device I am getting 6 for outgoing!

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused because based on the documentation here, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html . If you put the api below 24, you see REJECT_TYPE grayed out. Why does 5 still come back as a type then?

Answer (score 2):

Use the defined values, not discrete literal values:

```
CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE
CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE
CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE
```

Comment: the only problem with that is that some values are missing here (take a look at thinkpanda's answer)